# Flipping bits in PHP

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

Ok, the problem is :
You will be given a list of 32-bits unsigned integers in a file to read. You are required to output the list of the unsigned integers you get by flipping bits in its binary representation (i.e. unset bits must be set, and set bits must be unset).

The Sample input is:

```
3
2147483647
1
0
```

And the sample output is:

```
2147483648
4294967294
4294967295
```

Where the 3 in the input is the number of lines.

```
<?php

$_fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
$t = fgets($_fp);


for($i=0;$i<$t;$i++){
    $line = fgets($_fp);
    $binLine = decbin($line);
    $reverse = strrev($binLine);
    echo bindec($reverse)."\n";
}

fclose($_fp);
?>
```

How is this wrong? And should I be using bitwise operators instead?

Comment: When you say "set bits", do you mean the 1s?

Comment: yes, and unset means 0

Comment: And you simply want to turn all 1s into 0s and all 0s into 1s?

Comment: Take 1 for example, as unsigned 32-bits is 00000000000000000000000000000001 and doing the flipping we get 11111111111111111111111111111110 which in turn is 4294967294

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said *"unset bits must be set, and set bits must be unset"*. This is the result of [`XOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)-ing every bit of each number with `1`.

The code should read:

```
for($i=0;$i<$t;$i++){
    $line = fgets($_fp);
    echo(($line ^ 0xFFFFFFFF)."\n");       # 32-bit full of '1'
}
```

Comment: after looking at the truth tables I found this:                                                                                   
XOR Truth Table
Input Output
A B
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0

Comment: `XOR` stands for [`eXclusive OR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) and it means "either one or the other but not both on the same time". You can see from the truth table that `0` is the neutral element (it has no effect when combined using `XOR`) and `1` turns `0` to `1` and `1` to `0`. And this behaviour is exactly the fragment from the question I quoted in the answer (is displayed in italics). :-)

Answer (score 1):

32 bit binary value is 11111111111111111111111111111111 and convert to decimal which is 4294967295. Then, Do XOR between input value and 4294967295.

```
function flippingBits($n) {

   return $n ^ 4294967295;

}
$result = flippingBits(3);//any input

echo( $result . "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a mask with `bindec(str_repeat("1", 32))` and apply the flip operator `^`

```
decbin(2147483648^bindec(str_repeat("1", 32))) # "1111111111111111111111111111111"
```

For the integers with lower values, if you need them to get converted as 32 bit integers, you can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf('%032d', 1) # "00000000000000000000000000000001"
decbin(sprintf('%032d', 1)^bindec(str_repeat("1", 32))) # "11111111111111111111111111111110"
```

Comment: That 'flip operator' is called XOR, also creating a mask from a string is real overkill. A simple 1 << n (n = number of bits, 32 in your example) would suffice. << is a bitwise shift left.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out that code

```
<?php
$bin = sprintf( "%032d", decbin( 0 ));
$out = "";
for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($bin); $i++ ) {
    $char = substr( $bin, $i, 1 );
    $out .= ($char == 1 ) ? 0 : 1;
}
$dec = bindec($out);
print($out."\n");
print($dec);
?>
```